# why "not insertable-into" error when insert into mysql.user table from mysql console?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

from the mysql console, I run:

```
MariaDB [steve]> insert into mysql.user
    ->        (user,host,authentication_string,ssl_cipher,x509_issuer,x509_subject)
    ->        values('steve','localhost', PASSWORD('steve'), '','','');
```

get error:

```
ERROR 1471 (HY000): The target table user of the INSERT is not insertable-into
```

I am logged in as root:

```
PS C:\Users\srich> C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
```

How to create a new database user from the mysql console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user is created like a database or table object

```
CREATE USER 'user1'@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password1';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user1'@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password1'
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

more information:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-user/

and
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/